# Can the inlineformset_factory create a tabularInline?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have activity records that have an inline formset showing appointments. I use the inlinefomset_factory.

It works but it displays them as an equivalent to a StackedInline you find in InlineModelAdmin. However, I wondered if it can product tabularInline or if anyone has done anything similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahha! Yes you can, and here it is.

["Making a django inline (model) formset really tabular"](http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/1442/)